# Accessing deep root element in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

In the JSON file present in [this](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=cher&api_key=7f7b44d01ed230025661d846dcb84e30&format=json) link. How do I display the album names of different artists? I tried displaying the names of the album by writing:

```
var json = JSON.parse (request.responseText); //parses the string as JSON
var str  = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Album name: "+json.topalbums.album[name];
```

But, this didn't work out as well.

**Please Help**

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the element of the `topalbums` array which has the `name` you are looking for:

```
for (var i=0; i<json.topalbums.length; i++) {
    if (json.topalbums[i].name === name) {
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

If you're an underscore user, you can use `findWhere`:

```
album = _.findWhere(json.topalbums, {name: name});
```

That will give you the matching album object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am searching for the top albums by using the name of the artist. So, as per the link, if I input the artist's name as Cher, I should get all the top albums my Cher. Keeping this logic in mind, I modified the above code a bit:
    `for(var i=0; i<json.topalbums.length; i++)
      {
          if(json.topalbums.albums[i].name == artist )
          { document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = json.topalbums.albums[i].name; } }`